# How to refactor repeating IDbConnection.open\close?

Tags: refactoring, dapper, dbconnection

maybe its stupid question, but I confused my self.
I use Dapper with Autofac (DI) and in my business layer I always use the following construction:

```
db.Open(); //db is IDbConnection instance
db.InsertOrDeleteOrUpdate(...)
db.Close();
```

whether a good solution to hide db.Open() and db.Close() by delegate method? For example:

```
dbHelper.do(db => db.InsertOrDeleteOrUpdate(...));
```

What do you do in such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redundant code is not the only issue in this code. Your code is hitting the database for every action. This will hit the performance if your DBServer is deployed on remote machine. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622140/5779732) answer.

Have you ever come across UnitOfWork pattern? It is very good solution for handling connections on some higher level.

Connection Factory is another good alternative and it can be used with UnitOfWork. But I personally prefer only UnitOfWork.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029588/5779732) answer for sample code of UnitOfWork.

Once you choose from above, it is easy to reduce the redundancy by using "connection per request" pattern. You need to identify centralized location in your code where to create `DalSession` and where to dispose it.

Comment: Thx but connection for request in my case is not problem, connection pooling should working, see answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439409/open-close-sqlconnection-or-keep-open. Connection Factory and UnitOfWork can only open connection, in my DI realization I can db.Open on constructor, but it is not solution. And I dont want use Repository pattern when I have ORM.
I need simply refactor this code, we can abstract from db this.

Comment: You have ORM, that is why you should consider implementing UnitOfWork. Dapper does not provide out of the box implementation for it. That is why, I suggested a link that shows sample code.

Comment: UnitOfWork is not just transaction or connection; it is more. Really a good thing to learn and implement. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39909985/5779732